# CSS problem - gaps between divs

Tags: html, css, layout

I have designed a layout and i find some gaps in the stacking of divs over each other.

can some one help me http://uniquedl.com/3closets/about.html

[image]
and

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this in `style.css`:

```
img { display: block }
```

and you need to change the height on `.introduction .intro-message` to `384px`, to match the height of the image on the left.

Doing this solves both problems.

---

As an alternative to `img { display: block }`, you could instead do: `img { vertical-align:bottom }`. This also fixes.

[***See this answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904668/html5-vertical-spacing-issue-with-img/4906624#4906624) for a good explanation of what's going on here.

@Alohci explains it very nicely.

Comment: This answer does actually work, at least in Firefox, where I tested it.

Comment: Tested IE9 as well, this indeed fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `<div class="clear"></div>` in both instances there. I would say that the page is behaving as expected.

**Edit:** If you use Google Chrome to view this page, you can right click on an area and choose "inspect element". It will provide a window that will display the code as it's rendered by the browser, and on the right there will be another properties window that displays the css being assigned to the elements you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

in their div .introduction you have an image larger than the div itself, this must be the problem, including the other divs

Answer (score 1):

First gap: your class .`introduction` is having height of `384px` where else class `.intro-message` (which is a child of .introduction) is having a height of `390px`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for your website :http://uniquedl.com/3closets/about.html just make the style like

```
.introduction {
    height: 384px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then it will work