# HTML/CSS issues

Tags: html, css

I had a table on a site on one web host and it looked fine, now I moved to another host and the table is screwed up

HTML:

```
<div class="right">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <tdcolspan="3">
        <img alt="" src="../App_Themes/image1.png">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img  alt="" src="../App_Themes/image2.png">
    </td>
    <td>
        <iframe class="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" src="site.com">
        Your browser does not support iframes
        </iframe>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img alt="" src="../App_Themes/image3.png">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img alt="" src="../App_Themes/image4.png">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

What's happening is that there's a (approx) 2px gap between the rows and I can't understand why, I tried with the following CSS but with no luck:

```
.right tr td {padding: 0; margin:0px;}
.right tr {border-spacing: 0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
```

The images forms a border around the iframe and image 1 is 2px above 2 and 3, image 4 is 2px below image 2 and 3.

How can something simple like this break just because I move to another host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how switching hosts changed anything, but I think I can solve your problem.

First off, fix `<tdcolspan="3">` to `<td colspan="3">`. That's not the cause, but it's not good either.

Try adding this CSS:

```
table img {
    display: block
}
```

Or this:

```
table img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

I *think* you're facing the same issue as in these questions:

- [CSS problem - gaps between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004602/css-problem-gaps-between-divs/5004679#5004679)
- [Why does Opera 9 have a space between these two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090998/why-does-opera-9-have-a-space-between-these-two-images/5091030#5091030)
- [html5 vertical spacing issue with <img>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904668/html5-vertical-spacing-issue-with-img/4906624#4906624)

See here for a document providing extended detail on the issue:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/images,_tables,_and_mysterious_gaps

Comment: and don't forget the all time classic <a href="http://mzl.la/fXt5hr">Mysterious gaps</a> "Eric Meyer 2003"

Comment: I'm now very convinced I've got it right; I made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UFLtw/

Comment: you are right ;)  I can't get my link to work?? I'll go shorten it

Comment: @clairesuzy: Good link. You might want to take a look at the help link under the Add Comment button. You don't have to go typing an entire `<a href="">` to make a link :)

Comment: one last try (can't use markdown, how yukk!).. http://mzl.la/fXt5hr - Mysterious Gaps originally written by Eric Meyer in 2003

Answer (score -1):

Could be that you went from windows machine to linux machine or vica versa and the different line-ending is causing the different behavior.

Windows uses CRLF and Linux uses LF I think.

Possible solutions - convert the line endings in a good text editor to match server platform, otherwise, delete all the newline/whitespace between your TR tags to check if this is causing an issue.

Comment: I'm doubtful: line endings have little meaning, if none, in HTML.

Comment: Consider not the HTML spec - consider how Internet Explorer implement it