# Why does Opera 9 have a space between these two images?

Tags: html, css, browser, opera

Every other browser is rendering this correctly.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div><img src="img/logo_top.png" width="168" height="85" alt="Logo top" /></div>
        <div><img src="img/logo_bottom.png" width="168" height="83" alt="Logo bottom" /></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It's the same thing without the divs, and with a < br /> between images.

#### Update:

Here is my HTML, with doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            img {border: none;}
            body {font-size: 0px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div><img src="img/logo_top.png"  alt="Logo top" /></div>
            <div><img src="img/logo_bottom.png" alt="Logo bottom" /></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible that Opera makes breaks after divs ?! Eventually you can fix that with CSS.

Comment: What doctype are you using? (show your entire file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the issue I think it is, it should be fixed if you add this CSS:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Or this:

```
img {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: `<div>` display defaults to block. I think you mean to suggest changing it to `inline` or `inline-block`.

Comment: display: block; worked, thanks! :) Stackoverflow says I can accept an answer in 7 minutes so...

Comment: @Joel Etherton: You're right, `<div>` does default to block. However, I'm applying it to `<img>`.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904668/html5-vertical-spacing-issue-with-img/4906624#4906624) for a good explanation of the issue. That answer deserves more votes!

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I didn't read your answer closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the whitespace between the first `</div>` and the second `<div>`. Sometimes these CRLF whitespace characters are interpreted by the browser as an indication of physical space.

Comment: I tried that, still has a space between the images. Opera 10 and Opera 11 are ok, it's Opera 9 (ver. 9.50) that I'm having trouble with and the one browser my client is using of course...

Comment: @A-OK - You might try changing the style on both divs to `display: inline;`.