# Div gets extra height for no reason

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, height

I have some markup like so:

```
<div class="account-picture">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Mcr3l.png">
</div>
```

The `div` needs to be floated left. The image is 128px x 128px.

And some css:

```
.account-picture{
   float: left;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   font-size: 1px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

img{
   border: 1px solid #F8F8F8;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

But the problem is there seems to be some extra height assigned to the div.
The layout diagrams from firebug are as follows:
[image]

Why is the height of the div getting 2 extra pixels? Why does it vary across browsers?

- Firefox 12: 2px extra
- IE9: 0.26px extra
- Chrome: 0px extra.

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mWe5Y/

Why is this happening, and how do I get rid of that extra "height"?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because img is an inline element.

To get rid of that extra height:

```
.account-picture img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is this something that we can normalize in a reset stylesheet?

Comment: Is it safe to use img { display: block; } in a reset.css sheet?

Of course, but there will probably be times when you'll want <img> to be treated as an inline element. In those cases, you'll need to add CSS in the appropriate places to achieve that.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904668/html5-vertical-spacing-issue-with-img

Comment: Wow. Good fix. How did you find it out?

Comment: Why does the image being an inline element change the height of the parent element? If the inline image is only a certain height, why would the parent (seemingly arbitrarily) give extra height due to containing inline elements. Your answer helped me but I wish I could understand the reasoning better.