# <!DOCTYPE html> prevents me from resizing my <img>

Tags: html, image, doctype

Recently I fall in love with HTML5(especially games), and I realize I should strengthen my JavaScript first, hence, I read *Head First JavaScript(O'Reilly)* to take a crack.
I intended to display an **img** tag whose size is changing according to the different navigator size, but when I add **!DOCTYPE html**, **img** just cannot be resized.here is my simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>Pet</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/rock.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function resizeRock(){
                document.getElementById("rock").style.height = ( document.body.clientHeight - 100 ) * 0.9;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="resizeRock();">
        <div id="_rock">
            <img src="image/rock.png" alt="Rock" id="rock"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I remove **!DOCTYPE html**, everything goes well, but I'd like to know the reason, what's more, I'd like to know how to resize **img** tag in HTML5.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `<!DOCTYPE html>`, you put the document into standards mode.

There's a couple of changes you need to make to get this working. First, in standards mode, the page is only as high as it needs to be. So `document.body.clientHeight` is just the height of your image and a little bit of margin. To make the height of the page match that of the viewport, as happens by default in quirks mode add this CSS:

```
html, body { height:100% }
```

Second, in standards mode, you need to state the dimensions you're using when setting style.width and style.height. This is as easy as adding `+ "px"` to the end of the size setting line, making it

```
document.getElementById("rock").style.height = 
                                    ( document.body.clientHeight - 100 ) * 0.9 + "px";
```

Comment: I'm a green hand now,and I really appreciate your clear answer, adding `html, body { height:100% }` makes use of the whole page,yeah?Thanks again!

Comment: You could put it like that, but "page" is a bit vague in that context. More precisely, it makes the area covered by the body element at least as tall as the "viewport", but because the `html` and `body` elements are stylable elements, what really happens depends on the interaction of many CSS properties, and is far too complicated to fully explain here.

Comment: Due to your vivid description,I can sense the meaning,though I become painful when it comes to speaking it out.Are there some books or something else explaining the further principles?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `<img>` is being inline CSS element and you cannot set height for such elements.

Add:

```
 #rock {
       display: block;
 }
```

in your stylesheet.

Moer info

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4906624/315168

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sorry that doesn't work.And Alohci did good job.