# Strange css behaviour in meteor

Tags: css, meteor

I wrote a small web page without any functionality. When I open this page directly in a browser the white box will vertically resize with the browser. But if I run this in Meteor the white box won't get larger than 400px.

I compared all elements using the chrome tools but all css attributes seems to be identical in both versions.

To test it in a normal browser the stylesheet link must be enabled.

index.html:

```
<head>
</head>
    <!--link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/-->
<body>
   <div id="messages" class="relative content-box">
      <div id="chat-box" class=""></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

main.css:

```
body {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #004269; }

.content-box {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px; }

.relative {
  position: relative; }

#messages {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
  padding: 10px; }

#chat-box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: inherit;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden; }

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative; }

body {
  margin-bottom: 190px;
  margin-top: 112px; }

.content-box {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it's because of the  which is added by Meteor. This changes the size of the document height. More details can be found here:
[<!DOCTYPE html> prevents me from resizing my <img>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671962/doctype-html-prevents-me-from-resizing-my-img)