# Unwanted space inside of DIVs

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to place a slided image in the center if the page. I have it almost done, the thing is that inner each piece of the image I have a small space, like if it has some little padding (which it hasn't), does anybody sees something wrong in the code?

```html
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #wrapper, images {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
  }

  img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }

  .center {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    margin-top: -300px;
  }

  .center_mini {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }

  .center_mini_float {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }
</style>
<div class="center">
  <div class="center_mini">
    <img src="images/background_01.png" width="800" height="144" alt="bg">
    <div class="center_mini">
      <div class="center_mini_float">
        <img src="images/background_02.png" width="503" height="456" alt="bg">
      </div>
      <div class="center_mini_float">
        <div class="center_mini">
          <div class="center_mini">
            <img src="images/background_03.png" width="246" height="89" alt="bg">
          </div>
          <div class="center_mini">
            <img src="images/background_05.png" width="246" height="106" alt="bg">
          </div>
          <div class="center_mini">
            <img src="images/background_06.png" width="246" height="102" alt="bg">
          </div>
          <div class="center_mini">
            <img src="images/background_07.png" width="246" height="159" alt="bg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center_mini_float">
        <img src="images/background_04.png" width="51" height="456" alt="bg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--<img src="images/background.jpg" width="800" height="600" alt="bg">-->
</div>
```

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4906624/211627) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
img { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that IMG tags have a natural DISPLAY value of "INLINE". This causes extra whitespace to appear around the image in certain situations.

Depending on your layout needs, try

```
img { display: block; }
```

or

```
img { display:inline-block; }
```

If your images are otherwise working the way you want, inline-block will cause the least amount of thrash.

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp 
http://www.tequilafish.com/2009/04/29/css-removing-extra-space-underneath-an-image/

Comment: I'll give you a +1 if you can find __any__ other resource other than w3schools. :p

Comment: +0.9 (You lost 0.1 [for the w3schools link](http://w3fools.com/), but fortunately SO rounds up)

Comment: While I get this was tongue in cheek, I'm totally anti 733t hax0r attitudes. w3schools is a perfectly valid and useful reference — one of the most clear when it comes to seeing all possible properties and their effects.

Comment: @EllenB - I'm not a leet hackor. And w3schools is dangerously inaccurate for a beginner. They do have useful information, but they also have many omissions and flat out errors which can be confusing, frustrating and misleading to new users. (You can see a list of the errors on their site in the article linked above, and [again here](http://w3fools.com/#htmlsucks).)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Such as? Never had any problems with W3Schools

Comment: @EllenB Actually, images have a default display of inline-block, there's no need to specify it unless you've overwritten it elsewhere.

Comment: @EllenB - Shall I link to the [list of examples](http://w3fools.com/#htmlsucks) a [third time](http://w3fools.com/#htmlsucks)?

Comment: @Gordon - I believe you owe Ellen an upvote for that second link. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution will be using

```
img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

This way you won't alternate the default browser image display. Also, make sure the image container has line-height: 100%, that could be causing problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Images have `display:inline;` by default, that's what's causing the whitespace between your images. You can do three things to prevent this:

```
float:left;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

or

```
display:block;
```