# How can I eliminate the space between two divs inside a containing div in Live View?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm having annoyances lining up two divs so that they sit flush without any white space in between.
One div contains an image and sit's on top of the other which contains the navigation bar.
Both divs sit inside of a containing div.
The white space is no more than a few pixels tall. It does not appear when coding in Dreamweaver, only once viewed in browser or Live View is initiated.
The body of my document has a margin of 0. I have tried making the containing div's margin 0 without any luck. Also tried the padding. Experimented with float too. Nothing seems to work, it has to be something obvious but I have been stuck on this for a long time..

### Html:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="bannner">
<img src="images/banner.jpg" width="900px" height="350px" alt="banner"/>
</div><!--end of banner div-->
<div id="navbar"> 
<div class="hoveringNavBar" id="one">
<img class="icon" src="images/home.png">
<p class="text">Home</p>
</div>

<div class="hoveringNavBar" id="two">
<img class="icon" src="images/mains.png">
<p class="text">Mains</p>
</div>

<div class="hoveringNavBar" id="three">
<img class="icon" src="images/sandwich.png">
<p class="text">Sandwiches</p>
</div>

<div class="hoveringNavBar" id="four">
<img class="icon" src="images/desserts.png">
<p class="text">Desserts</p>
</div>              
</div><!--end of navbar-->
</div><!--end of header-->
```

### css:

```
#header
margin:auto;
height:530px;
width:900px;
background-color:#F8F8F8;

#banner
margin:0px; 

#navbar
margin: 0px;
height: 180px;
width: 900px;
background-color: red;
```

Comment: A screenshot or link would help. maybe the margin and padding from the `<p class="text">` tag? `<p>` by default have some margin. Try adding `p { margin:0; padding:0; }` to your CSS.

Comment: which white space area are you referring to? Have you tried set the height of #banner to 360px?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a jsFiddle.net example? For images, either point to the ones on your server, or use generic placeholders by using a service like placehold.it or placekitten.com.

Comment: yea i can't edit my post with an image due to rep points not being 10 i'll make a link

Comment: http://s1377.photobucket.com/user/ebenhafkamp/media/dwscreen_zpsa31a1f20.jpg.html

Comment: So your problem is the white space between the large image and those thumbnails?

Comment: Yeap, that is the space. I just couldn't get the two divs to sit flush and ran out of idea's until the absolute from top pixel solution

Comment: As you can see here, the problem is not the div, but the image: http://fiddle.jshell.net/XHL4B/2/

Comment: Just add #banner img { display:block } and voilá! ;)
As an extra, you have a typo on you code: `<div id="bannner">` triple n, should read banner.

Comment: I've noticed it only happens with HTML5 doctype. If you use XHMTL doctype, that gap won't exist.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: the difference in why it doesn't appear in xhtml is too technical for me to comprehend lol the miss spelled word was a really bad mistake yet not crucial. the display block in #banner img did the trick! cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the height for banner div.

```
#banner{
 height:350px;
}
```

or give your image a display block

```
 #banner img{
   display:block;
 }
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Right. But only needed if using HTML5 doctype. For XHTML doctype, the gap won't be there.

Comment: I tried both the height editing of banner and adding a display block style but neither works. The banner is already 350px set in html, adding to css doesn't seem to make any changes

Comment: You have a typo in you code. `bannner` instead of `banner`. You CSS is not being applied.

Comment: To note: When i swap the banner and navigation bar around the gap disappears and the navbar sits flush with the top of the document :S

Comment: FAR OUT. That does it too. Doing that in conjunction with the display block does the trick! Thank you so much for the solution to the more technical and correct problem at hand! :D Silly me :(

Comment: Could i ask you to elaborate why display:block makes all the difference. Why would my divs not align without it?

Comment: You can read the post here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904668/html5-vertical-spacing-issue-with-img

Comment: In "Standards" mode of your web browser, the line box always contains the space for the descenders of characters like g, p and y below the baseline, even if there are no real characters in that line box.The gap you see is the distance between the baseline and the bottom of the line box which is the space for those descenders.

Comment: Sorry deleted the comment because i realized display:block does work but has to be used in conjunction with #banner img. Thanks for the further explanation, i obviously have a way to go :P

Answer (score 0):

Try to use position:relative; or position:absolute; then top:numberpx; or left:whateverpx; to align your CSS boxes.

Comment: Thank You! You're a time saver haha! Made container relative and navbar absolute then applied top for navbar to 350px which is the length of my banner! Thank you so much! I would vote you up but i don't have enough rep points..

Comment: @EbenHafkamp it always helps me XD I use those positions ALL the time with CSS XD, glad it helped. Please accept my answer :)

Comment: Although it works, that shouldn't be the way of doing it. If there is space between two consecutive divs, something is messing with it.

Comment: Yeap I will definitely be using this method more often! :)

Comment: It could be that your divs are not ordered correctly, but just mess around with it, if you can't figure it out then I would stick to that, but it is a useful method for the future :)

Comment: @rjpedrosa Yea for sure, but I tried everything, I even deconstructed the code in a new site but the problem arose straight away. Nothing to do with original banner image either so for now i'm just relieved to have a solution

Comment: I know the feeling, I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using position for such a simple task. If you can provide us a jsfiddle link, we can help you out

Comment: I have reproduced your code in here http://fiddle.jshell.net/XHL4B/ , but can't understand what your problem is...

Comment: reproduced code with visible space via codepen http://codepen.io/Hafkamp/pen/yrhCz

Answer (score 0):

**`#banner img{
   display:block;
 }`**

is the right answer.

Images are displayed "inline" by default:
http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_CSS_layout_model_-_boxes_borders_margins_padding#Element_types_and_the_display_property

As a test, set the image to display:block, then change it to display:inline and watch the whitespace appear and disappear.

Comment: This problem plagued me too; I solved it using Opera's developer tools, and finding that the "computed" style of the image was "inline."  Who knew?